# Suppose limit as x approaches 0 of the derivative of f(x)=a. Show that the derivative at 0 exists and it is equal to a.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let f be a continuous function on the interval [0,1], which is differentiable on (0,1).

I know that I will have to use the definition of a derivative, which is the limit as x approaches 0 f(x)-f(0)/(x-0)

Comment: Do you remember the mean value theorem?

Comment: If someone agrees with me they can vote to close as duplicate and I will vote also.